# Getting iTunes lyrics usings osascript

Tags: applescript, itunes, osascript

I'm trying to get the lyrics to the current playing song in iTunes using `osascript`. The command I'm using is:

```
osascript -e '''tell application "iTunes" to lyrics of the current track'''
```

The problem with this is that I'm only getting the last line of the lyrics when I run it on the terminal.

Is it possible to get the full lyrics without first copying them to a temp file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, iTunes uses the **CR** (carriage return) character instead of the **LF** (line feed) character to separate the lines of song lyrics. Carriage return – well, *returns* the cursor to the leftmost position without switching to the next line, which is why you only see the last line in a Terminal output. This is easily fixed by piping the output to the `tr` utility (tr for translate) and replacing the CRs by LFs using shell escape codes `\r` and `\n`:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "iTunes" to lyrics of current track' | tr '\r' '\n'
```